# Need help converting this joined table TSQL statement to Linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I looked at some of the other related questions, but didn't find a good answer.  My TSQL query works fine:

```
SELECT POR.ReqNum ,
   POR.ReqLine ,
   XF.* -- Expand this..
   FROM   E10DB.Erp.PORel POR
   INNER JOIN E10DB.Erp.ReqDetail RD ON RD.ReqNum = POR.ReqNum
   INNER JOIN E10DB.Ice.XFileAttch XF ON XF.Key1 = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), 
      RD.ReqNum)
   WHERE  POR.PONum = @ponum
      AND RD.Company = @company
      AND XF.Company = @company;
```

I would like to translate this into a LINQ result like:

```
var joinResultRows = from PORel , etc.,...........
```

so I can do loop through them to do something :

```
 foreach(var joinResult in joinResultRows)
 {
     string custID = joinResult.CustID;
     string ponum = joinResult.PONum;
 }
```

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: are you familiar with a tool called LinqPad..? or look up Linqer

Comment: LinqPad just executes the queries you throw at it, I didn't see any translation.  Linqer bargs while trying to generate the models.

Comment: `var joinResultRows =  from poRelRow in Db.PORel
                           join detailRow in Db.ReqDetail
            on new {  poRelRow.ReqNum } equals new { detailRow.ReqNum }
            join xfRow in Db.XFileAttch
            on new { detailRow.ReqNum.ToString() } equals new { xfRow.Key1 }
             select new {poRelRow.ReqNum, poRelRow.ReqLine, xfRow.DrawDesc, xfRow.XFileRefNum, xfRow.FileName, xfRow.DocTypeID };`